# no se logra pasar el id a un modal

Tags: javascript, php

Buenas tardes compañeros, hace una semana que vengo luchando con mi codigo de una tabla donde puedo deshabilitar a un usuario(rol administrador) y para ello necesito utilizar un modal(siendo mas "dinamico" y pedido por la facultad) donde se pase dicho valor de la variable id y luego poder actulizarlo.
Muestra el modal utilizando el boton pero a la hora de visualizarla el modal lo que me muestra es el siguiente error:
[image: Error al Eliminar el usuario], aclaro que no eh tenido problemas de tipo  *mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean*
posiblemente sea un problema muy tonto que no me doy cuenta, desde ya agradezco mucho a quien me pueda responder :)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Administrador</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" 
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap- 
    icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body class="cuerpo-principal">
    <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark  bg-dark">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
                target="#opciones">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="./administrador.php">
                <img src="../img/icono.png" width="100px" height="70px" alt="logo"></a>
            </nav> 
            </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- Modal deshabilitar usuario-->

    <div class="modal fade lg" id="desactivarUsuario" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
    labelledby="desactivarUsuarioLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="desactivarUsuarioLabel">Deshabilitar usuario</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
       <?php
        

        if(isset($_POST['deshabilitarUsuario'])){

            $idUsuario=$_POST['deshabilitarUsuario'];

            $query_desactivar=mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE usuarios SET estado=0 WHERE 
            idUsuarios=$idUsuario");


            if($query_desactivar){
                //si se borra , el administrador es devuelto a la pagina del listado 
                header('location:listaUsuarios.php');
            }else{
                //sino tira un error con una frase
                echo "Error al Eliminar el usuario";
            }
    
        $query=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT u.nombre,u.apellido,u.email
                                            FROM usuarios u
                                            WHERE u.idUsuarios=$idUsuario");
            
        $resultado=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
            if($resultado>0){
                while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    $nombre=$data['nombre'];
                    $apellido=$data['apellido'];
                    $email=$data['email'];
                }
            }
        }
    ?>


    <form action="" method="POST">
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="container">
        <input type="hidden" name="deshabilitarUsuario" id="deshabilitarUsuario">
          <p class="titulo-formulario">¿Esta seguro que desea desactivar la cuenta del usuario 
           </p>
          <p>Nombre:<span><?php echo $nombre;?></span></p>

          <p>Apellido:<span><?php echo $apellido;?></span></p>

          <p>Email:<span><?php echo $email;?></span></p>     

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" 
           href="listaUsuarios.php">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
            </div>
           </div>
          </form>
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="titulo">Lista de usuarios:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="./buscarActivado.php" method="get" class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control mr-2" type="text" name="busqueda" placeholder="Ingrese la 
         busqueda" id="busqueda">
        <button class="btn btn-primary ms-1" type="submit" value="btn-search"><i class="bi bi- 
        search"></i>Buscador</button>
    </form>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="container"> 
        <div class="table-responsive-lg">
            <table class="table table-hover table-dark" id="example"  data-order='[[ 0, "asc" ]]' 
            data-page-length='2'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Id Usuario</th>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Nombre</th>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Apellido</th>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Numero de DNI</th>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th class="text-center" scope="col">Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                
                <?php
                    
                    $sql_registro=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_registro FROM 
                    usuarios WHERE idRoles<2");
                    $resultado_registro=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_registro);
                    $total_registro=$resultado_registro['total_registro'];
                    
                    $por_pagina=8;

                    if(empty($_GET['pagina'])){
                        $pagina=1 ;
                    }else{
                        $pagina=$_GET['pagina'];
                    }
                    $desde=($pagina-1) * $por_pagina ;
                    $total_paginas=ceil($total_registro/$por_pagina);
                    
                    $query= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT 
                    u.idUsuarios,u.nombre,u.apellido,u.numeroDocumento,u.email,u.estado,r.tipo 
                    FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN roles r ON u.idRoles=r.idRoles
                                                    WHERE u.idRoles<2 LIMIT $desde,$por_pagina");
                    $resultado=mysqli_num_rows($query);

                    if($resultado >0){
                        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){    
                            
                            
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $data['idUsuarios']; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $data['nombre']; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $data['apellido']; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $data['numeroDocumento']; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $data['email']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                    <?php

                        if(($data['idUsuarios']!=1 && $data['estado']==1)){
                    ?>
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 mx-4">
                        
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-block desactivarUsuario"  data-bs- 
                       toggle="modal" 
                        role="button" data-bs-target="#desactivarUsuario"><i class='bi bi-x- 
                        circle'></i> Desactivar usuario</a>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                        }else if($data['idUsuarios']!=1 && $data['estado']==0){
                    ?>
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 mx-4">
                            <a class="btn btn-success btn-block central-block" 
                            href="activarUsuario.php?id=<?php echo $data['idUsuarios'];?>"
                             role="button"><i class="bi bi-check2-circle"></i> Activar usuario</a>
                            </td>
                        </div>

                        <?php 
                            }
                        ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
            <tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            <nav class="mt-3">
                <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                    <li class="page-item">
                    <?php

                    for($i=1;$i<=$total_paginas;$i++){
                        echo'<li><a class="page-link" href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
                </div>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('desactivarUsuario').on('click',function(){
                    $('#desactivarUsuario').modal('show');

                    $tr=$(this).closest('tr');

                    var dato= $tr.children("td").map(function(){
                        return $(this).text();
                    }).get();

                    console.log(dato);
                    $('#deshabilitarUsuario').val(dato['idUsuarios']);

                });
            });
        </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
     integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Hola, no se si pudieras editar la pregunta y corregir bien los comentarios, se entrelazan con el código y no está muy bien visible

Comment: hola que tal, saque todo lo comentado que tenia, la pregunta es porque no se pasa el valor del id (que estoy "levantando) que se dispara cuando toco el boton?

Comment: me muestra le modal pero el valor que se pasa en el id es vacio, y a la hora de poder pasarlo al form no me deja realizar el update como tambien el de mostrar sus otros campos(nombre,apellido y email) .. nose si se aclare la pregunta

Comment: no, saque el alias, pero sigue tirando el mismo erro: primero que no puede actualizar el estado y luego que no están definidas las variables de los campos de nombre, apellido y email

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tu codigo tienes varios problemas... que no son de codigo...

Primero, el error de mysqli...
mysqli requiere la referencia a la conexion que estas usando...
por lo que deberas corregir la linea que te causa el error, incluyendo la conexion (cosa que ya haces en otras lineas)

```
$resultado=mysqli_num_rows($conexion, $query);//esta es la forma correcta
```

segundo, no recibes el "id" por que nunca lo mandas...
tienes un input que no tiene un valor, lo correcto seria:

```
<input type="hidden" name="deshabilitarUsuario" id="deshabilitarUsuario" **value="<?php echo $idUsuario; ?>"**> //o algo muy similar :D
```

En cuanto a los demas errores, son consecuencia de estos dos...

Es muy importante revisar con cuidado tanto la sintaxis como el contenido, espero que esto ayude a resolver tu problema.

Comment: probé con lo que dijiste pero me sigue expresando que las variables no se ... encuentran definidas, lo del id tenias toda la razón no le pasaba el valor

Comment: resulta obvio que no se se esta ejecutando el loop donde asignas las variables (lo tienes un poco antes), prueba a hacer un dump de tu resultado del query directamente con echo o error_log

Comment: no le pasa el valor

Comment: actualiza tu codigo y tu pantalla de salida, lo mas probable es el while o la condicion antes de el

Comment: Muestra el siguiente error en la consola **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at listaUsuarios.php:214:4**

Comment: y el error es una linea de codigo de java script 'console.log(dato);'

Comment: Tienes mal algun closure de php...